# How do I compare two text areas and check for duplicates with the same string and same position in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to compare two textarea. count all words/strings in textarea 1 having the same string and positioning.

For example:

Textarea 1:
Apple 
Banana Orange

Textarea 2:
Apple Orange 
Banana

In the example, apple and banana are counted as correct having the same string and right positions while orange is wrong.

Is this possible in javascript? Please point me in the right direction.

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but ***you need to help yourself first. :-)*** After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: in this case simple string comparison will do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's another way:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

 $(".btn").click(function () {
    
    var msg1Lines = $(".area1").val().split("\n"); //split text into lines
    var msg2Lines = $(".area2").val().split("\n"); //split text into lines
    var stopIndex;
    
    if(msg1Lines.length > msg2Lines.length) //determine which text area has more lines
    {
      stopIndex = msg2Lines.length;
    }
    else
    {
      stopIndex = msg1Lines.length;
    }
    
    for(i = 0; i < stopIndex; i++) //for each line in the message with the fewest number of lines
    {
        var msg2LineWords = msg2Lines[i].split(" ");
        for(j = 0; j < msg2LineWords.length; j++) //for each word in 2nd textarea
        {
          if(msg1Lines[i].search(msg2LineWords[j]) != msg2Lines[i].search(msg2LineWords[j])) //if word does not start at same index in both text areas
          {
               $(".difference").val($(".difference").val() + msg2LineWords[j] + "\n"); //display results in third textarea
          }
        }
       
    }
   
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea class="area1">
Apple
Banana Orange
</textarea>

<textarea class="area2">
Apple Orange
Banana
</textarea>

<button class="btn" style="display: block; margin-top: 10px;">Test</button>

<p style="display: block; margin-top: 10px;">
Incorrect: 
</p>
<textarea class="difference" style="display: block; margin-top: 10px;"></textarea>
```

Comment: Thank you! This works very well too! Finally I can move on

Answer (score 0):

First save the two text areas as strings then run them through a split. after that run them through a for each loop to check if strings match.

```
textArea1 = "Apple Banana Orange";
textArea2 = "Apple Orange Banana";

array1 = textArea1.split(" ");
array2 = textArea2.split(" ");

for (i = 0; i < array1.length; i ++) {
  if(array1[i] == array2[i]) {
    console.log("Match");
  } else {
    console.log("Mismatch");
  }
}
```

Or something like that;

Comment: Oh my goodness split works! thanks! everytime i search for anything about this all i get is substring/substr & slice. Thank you so much! Big help!